# how to see raw request body in yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

For debugging, I'd like to see raw request bodies that are being sent
to my yesod application.

I know how to use `runRequestBody` https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.0/yesod-core-1.4.24/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:runRequestBody

Now there is `rawRequestBody`. I am using

```
rawRequestBody Data.Conduit.$$ Data.Conduit.List.consume
```

inside `defaultLayout` but the result is always empty.

The actual representation is a Conduit, so I suspect that it is already drained at this point. Then when do I get to see this in a state where it holds data? Assume this is possible, then how can I read it without removing its contents?

Comment: Have you run anything before the call to `rawRequestBody` which may have called `runRequestBody` or similar? Any kind of POST form processing could do that.

Comment: Yes, this is in a handler for POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import qualified Data.Conduit.Text as CT
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

rawRequestBody $$ CT.decode CT.utf8 =$ CL.consume
```